# Culling edges from a graph using XSLT

Tags: xslt, graph

I have a directed graph represented in XML, as shown in the minimalistic example below. I am looking for a way to programmatically cull redundant edges to create a minimized digraph.

Specifically, A -> B -> C, so I don't need the link directly from A -> C: the relationship between A and C is already implied by the relationships between A and B, and between B and C.

I start with

```
<graph>
  <node id="A" />
  <node id="B" />
  <node id="C" />
  <edge src="A" dest="B" />
  <edge src="A" dest="C" />
  <edge src="B" dest="C" />
</graph>
```

What I want is

```
<graph>
  <node id="A" />
  <node id="B" />
  <node id="C" />
  <edge src="A" dest="B" />
  <edge src="B" dest="C" />
</graph>
```

I'm pretty sure I'm looking for an `<xsl:template>` with a matching rule that says something like "edge that has two siblings such that one has the same src as me, the other has the same dest as me, and they match on their respective dest and source vales" (which is a mouthful even in English). I can't see how to phrase this as a template match pattern, or even a selection within the template. I can see how to do it by examination (comparing each pair of siblings to see if I can cull this one), but I'd prefer to avoid it: it would work, and I don't have so many edges that I'm particularly concerned about the O(nn) runtime, but it's inelegant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tried to use XSLT (2 or 3) to specify your pattern condition:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:variable name="edges" select="/graph/edge"/>

  <xsl:template match="edge[some $edge1 in ($edges except .) 
                            satisfies 
                              $edge1/@src = @src
                              and 
                              (some $edge2 in ($edges except (., $edge1))
                               satisfies ($edge2/@dest = @dest and $edge1/@dest = $edge2/@src))]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result is (https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiZQaFb)

```
<graph>
  <node id="A"/>
  <node id="B"/>
  <node id="C"/>
  <edge src="A" dest="B"/>

  <edge src="B" dest="C"/>
</graph>
```

so it has excluded the `edge` element you want to eliminate. I can't really assess whether that has any value for the general problem to remove redundant edges, tell us whether it helps.

Note that if you use XSLT 2 you need to replace the `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` with the identity transformation template.

To find the other edges one could also use keys:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:variable name="edges" select="/graph/edge"/>

  <xsl:key name="src" match="edge" use="@src"/>
  <xsl:key name="dest" match="edge" use="@dest"/>

  <xsl:template match="edge[some $edge1 in (key('src', @src) except .) 
                            satisfies 
                              some $edge2 in (key('dest', @dest) except (., $edge1))
                              satisfies $edge1/@dest = $edge2/@src]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiZQaFb/1

Comment: This does not do _exactly_ what I need, but it does what I asked :) My example was insufficient (I have many graphs containing nodes and edges, located deeper in my data). You gave me the hint I needed (I hadn't even heard of this extended match syntax, time for some reading) and I was able to figure out how to apply it to my goal.